# Able to / good way to cover / handle cleanout in the floor

Tags: basement, floor, pipe, cleanout

I am trying to install vinyl plank flooring in my basement and the cleanout is right in the middle of the floor unfortunately. Am I able to cover it and/or is there a good way to handle putting the flooring down around or over the cleanout?

Image:

[image]

thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. How far above the level of the floor does the plug extend? Any chance you can get it flush or below?

Comment: It'd about a quarter inch above the floor. I would love to get it level and cover it but I don't know if that is OK. I also don't know what the pipe I used for.

Comment: You (and whomever resides there after you) may need access to that in the future, unless it's confirmed out of service. I would start thinking of ways to hide it with furniture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would fit your flooring neatly around the clean-out rim, and then screw down a stainless steel cover plate that laps onto the flooring. You can run the screw right into the cleanout plug.

The clean-out is presumably for your main sewer line, which probably runs under the floor and out to the street or septic system. If you ever have a backup you'll kick yourself if you had covered it up.